# *ngIf not working in child component in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9, angular-ng-if

ngIf is not working in child component. There are two sibling components (Release and Assets) and both have a shared component (version-actions), and both the sibling components are essentially inside two different mat-tab tags in the parent component.

If the tab selected is Release then a particular button/img is to be hidden in the shared component.

**.HTML**

```
 <div
    class="w-1/3 flex flex-row items-center"
  >
    <span
      class="flex items-center"
      title="Restore"
      matTooltip="Restore Version"
    >
    <ng-container *ngIf="isRelease === true">
      <button (click)="restoreVersion()">
        <img
          alt="Restore"
          id="restore-button"
          style="height: 2.25em;"
          src="/assets/icons/reload.png"
          class="px-2 py-2 text-gray-600 text-lg cursor-pointer"
        />
      </button>
    </ng-container>
    </span>
  </div>
```

I tried ngIf inside the span and button tags also (removing ng-container), but it is not working.

**.TS**

```
agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isRelease = this.params.release;
  }
```

If I use [style.display]='isRelease===true', then it is working as desired, but I want to know the exact reason why ngIf is not working here and what are the possible solutions.

CommonModule is also imported in module file of version-actions, as well as in Assets and Release.

**Edit**

I used [style.display]="isRelease? 'none':null" and not what I mentioned above.

Just to check, I used ngIf="true" and to my surprise it is still hiding the button.

**Update**

It was fixed. There was problem with the module files. exported the parents module file to the children's and it started working. If anyone facing similar issue under similar circumstances, try different things with module files.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Can you post a link to stackblitz?

Comment: When and how is `agInit` called?

Answer (score 0):

first ,sure you added this modules in your app module:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and
what's type of this.params.release ?

note that "===" operator checks type of operands. type for example:

```
 (1 === true) => false
 (1 == true) => true
```

so try ngIf condition  like this

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="isRelease">
```

and this **[style.display]='isRelease===true'** dose not mean ,
you should do it like this and then try it :

```
 [style.display]="isRelease ? 'none' : 'block'"
```

Comment: So, just to check whether ngIf would work, I put in the condition ngIf="true", and to my surprise, the button is hidden even if condition is true. If I remove whole of ngIf, then the button is visisble.  And the type of this.params.release is boolean.

Comment: Is it a Url parameter? If so cannot pass booleans, they are converted to string, you need to recast to boolean

Comment: so do you get any error in console?
and Are you sure that you imported CommonModule from @angular/common"

Comment: No error in console, and I am sure I imported CommonModule from @angular/common

Comment: It is not a Url parameter.

Comment: I only can say if you can make a stackblitz sample for this wondering !!!! :D

Comment: It got fixed. There was problem with the module file. exported the parents module file to the children's and it started working.